# Plotting train and eval scores for a model in R

Tags: r, plot, xgboost

How do I plot the train and test `AUC` scores which are being printed below ( refer to image) on a plot in R?

I am using `xgb.train` model below

```
train.gdbt <- xgb.train(params=list(objective="binary:logistic", eval_metric="auc", eta=0.5, max_depth=4, subsample=1, colsample_bytree=0.5), data=dtrain, nrounds=500, watchlist=list(eval=dtest, train=dtrain),verbose = 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should get the `evaluation_log` from the `xgb`, modify it to long format and then plot in two colors:

```
train.gdbt$evaluation_log %>%
  gather(key=test_or_train, value=AUC, eval_auc, train_auc) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = iter, y = AUC, group = test_or_train, color = test_or_train)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image: Test & Train AUC plot]

Comment: Thanks ! this is what i was wanting :)